# How to make a variable constantly update with python

Tags: python, function, variables

I am trying to make a clicker-based game with python and I'm trying to make an upgrade.

```
def silvercoinX():
   global x
   x=1
   return x
x = silvercoinX()
def silvercoinYUpdate():
   y=10
   y += round(y*1.33)
   return y
y = silvercoinYUpdate()
silvercoinYUpdate()
print(round(y))
silvercoinYUpdate()
print(round(y))
silvercoinYUpdate()
print(round(y))
```

Output

```
23

23

23
```

I'm trying to make the output

```
23

31 # (this being 23*1.33)

41 # (this being 31*1.33)
```

The X is going to be how much you get when you click

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are printing all the y values, not sure if that is what you meant to do. Since, you are calling function silvercoinYUpdate() three times, all that function is doing is adding 10 with round(10*1.33) which gives you 23 everytime you print it.

It looks like you do not even need x here if you want to return

```
23
31
41
```

Just declare y outside the function silvercoinYUpdate() .

```
    y = 10
    def silvercoinYUpdate():
       global y
       if y <= 10:
          y += round(y * 1.33)
       else:
          y = round(y*1.33)
       return y
    silvercoinYUpdate()
    print(y)
    silvercoinYUpdate()
    print(y)
    silvercoinYUpdate()
    print(y)
```

If you do not use if else statement, you will get your output as:

```
23
54
```

and so on. I am assuming you are going to use 10 as your initial value. Otherwise set your if-else statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Beware this is constant

```
def silvercoinYUpdate():
   y=10
   y += round(y*1.33)
   return y
# same as
def silvercoinYUpdate():
   y = 10  # you reset it here
   y = 10 + round(10*1.33)
   y = 10 + round(13.3)
   y = 23
   return 23
```

You maybe want something like this:

```
def silvercoinYUpdate(y=10):
   y += round(y*1.33)
   return y
y = silvercoinYUpdate() # 23
y = silvercoinYUpdate(y) # 31
```

or

```
y=10
def silvercoinYUpdate():
   global y
   y += round(y*1.33)
   return y
silvercoinYUpdate() # 23
silvercoinYUpdate() # 31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     import time
     y = 10                                                                        
     def silvercoinYUpdate():
         global y
         y += y * 1.33
         return y
     while True:
         print(silvercoinYUpdate())
         time.sleep(10)
         if(y >=100):
               break
```

This is my way of updating things. I will use time module for refreshing things while not make it more complex like refreshing entire display screen which usually game developers use. This way you can update y as many time as possible with correct condition to break and declare y in global because it will come constant 23 forever and loop will never breaks

Answer (score 0):

The silvercoinYUpdate function now takes y as an argument and returns the updated value. This allows you to pass the current value of y to the function and get the updated value.

Removed the global variable x and used it directly.

Introduced a loop to simulate multiple upgrades. You can adjust the number of upgrades by changing the range.

```
def silvercoinYUpdate(y):
    y += round(y * 1.33)
    return y

x = 1
y = 10

# Upgrade loop
for _ in range(3):  # You can adjust the number of upgrades
    y = silvercoinYUpdate(y)
    print(round(y))
```